# Easy access to Outlook Calendar and Inbox from 2 different accounts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, user-interface, command-line-arguments

I am trying to help someone in the following situation. She has two accounts in Outlook (both in the one Profile she has). She always uses the Inbox of Account1 but the Calendar of Account2. She wants Outlook to start up displaying the Account2 Calendar, so we have set it up so that “Start Outlook in this folder” in Outlook options/Advanced is set to that Calendar, and that works just fine.

However then she clicks on the Mail icon on the bottom left, and it drops her into the Inbox for Account2, not Account1.

She tells me that at one point it used to work fine:

- It would open up display Account2’s Calendar
- Then upon clicking the Mail icon(lower left) it would display Account1’s Inbox.

I can’t seem to find a way to make it do that. I tried a work around creating two icons one for the calendar and one for the inbox using the Outlook command line switch “/select outlook:inbox” but it then opens the inbox for Account2, not Account1, and I don’t know how to tell that switch how to differentiate between the Inboxes.

She is very non-technical, so we are trying to come up with one click access to these elements of her Outlook, so she doesn’t have to go to the folder list and scroll through it all.

So my question is this: given that Outlook starts up in the Calendar for Account2, how can we make it go back to working that clicking on the Mail icon in the lower left brings up the Inbox for AccountONE?

Or alternatively, how can I create shortcut icons for each of these folders in the desktop that take me to the folder under the right account instead of the similarly named folder under the wrong account (I can't change the names)?

Comment: Would she be satisfied with exporting the calendar from Acct2 to Acct1?

Comment: Nope. I did discover how to create direct shortcuts to folders within email accounts using the switch "/select outlook://acountname/foldername" so hopefully she will accept and embrace having two different icons, but it still deeply disturbs me how she had this functionality before (of clicking the mail icon to get the Acount1 Inbox) and does not have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, when clicking the Mail icon in the navigation pane, the Inbox folder of the primary account prompts. You may need to set Account 1 as the default account in the Outlook profile and set Outlook to start up displaying the Account2 Calendar via File > Options > Advanced. 
[image]

Comment: I have done that, but it doesn't help. I think it's going to the Account2 Inbox because I am already in the Account2 Calendar, but according to her it didn't used to do that, it used to always go to the Account1 Inbox, no matter what folder you were currently in (including the Account2 Calendar).

Comment: May I know the version information of your Outlook? I tested in my Outlook for Office 365 and it worked fine. Besides, what if testing by recreating a new profile for the user by adding Account 1 first to check the result?

Comment: It has now become a moot point, as she is happy with the two taskbar shortcut solution I provided. But thank you for your help. :)